# Probably a simple uniform convergence question

Tags: real-analysis

I'm to show that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{cos(nx)}{n^2+1}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Does it suffice to say that since $| cos(nx)| \leq 1$ for all n $\in \mathbb{N}$ and all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{cos(nx)}{n^2+1} \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+1}$

the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+1}$ converges and so by Weierstrass' M-test

the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{cos(nx)}{n^2+1}$ converges as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: since you have, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$\left| \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2+1} \right| \le \frac{1}{n^2+1}$$
and since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+1}$ converges, you have uniform convergence by the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test).